# Reading XML file from /res/xml using InputStream reader yields invalid characters / encoded data

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having trouble reading in XML data from an XML resource located in /res/xml/testxml.xml. For some reason using examples from my book and online, I'm not able to read the data properly. The following method is simple; read the XML resource and print the lines within it.

```
public InputStream fetchLocalStream(String file){
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        //in = Global.gContext.openFileInput("testxml.xml");
        in = Global.gContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.testxml);
        try {
             if (in != null) {
                  // prepare the file for reading
                  InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                  BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

                  String line;

                  // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
                  while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                      Log.d(Global.TAG,"-->Line:" + line);
                    // do something with the settings from the file
                  }

                }
            } catch (Exception e){}


            return in;
    }catch (Exception e){ Log.d(Global.TAG,"--> Failed!!!!" + e); }
    return in;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Line:└Ç└Ç└Ç∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜♥└Ç└Ç└Ç#└Ç└Ç└Ç¶└Ç¶└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç♦☺►└Ç∟└Ç└Ç└Ç
Line:└Ç└Ç└Ç∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜$└Ç└Ç└└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç♥☺►└Ç↑└Ç└Ç└Ç
Line:└Ç└Ç└Ç∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜♥└Ç└Ç└Ç#└Ç└Ç└Ç☻☺►└Ç$└Ç└Ç└Ç
Line:└Ç└Ç└Ç∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜♥└Ç└Ç└Ç%└Ç└Ç└Ç¶└Ç¶└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç♦☺►└Ç∟└Ç└Ç└Ç
Line:└Ç└Ç└Ç∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜&└Ç└Ç└└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç♥☺►└Ç↑└Ç└Ç└Ç
Line:└Ç└Ç└Ç∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜∩┐╜♥└Ç└Ç└Ç%└Ç└Ç└Ç☻☺►└ÇL└Ç└Ç└Ç
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution in the thread "[Android SAX xml not well-formed](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/android-sax-xml-not-well-formed-t4314.html)" over at anddev.org:

> Found out an interesting stuff - when moving xml file from xml folder to raw, everything works smoothly. I guess that's why the function is called openRawResource . 
>   Anyways i think that android adds some stuff to the files stored in non raw folder. But this is just a thinking aloud.

Moving from /res/xml to /res/raw solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably a character encoding issue. Try using the [XmlResourceParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html), which you can obtain via [Resources.getXml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml%28int%29). (Most XML parsers are adapt at dealing with character encoding.) [Here's an example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: How do I specify the encoding type? Eclipse shows it as UTF-8. I do want to keep the implementation as is so I do not need to adapt other methods and continue to use the InputStream type for reponses from HTTP instead.

Comment: One way to do it would be to create the InputStreamReader as  `InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @Kevin: Could you post the first few lines of the actual XML file?